# $state is not recognized inside the callback of $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having a problem that $state is not recognized inside my "on" event function.

This is my code:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (evt, toState) {
        if (!sessionStorage.token)
          $state.go('main');                
    });
}]);
```

I even tried to add

```
$rootScope.$state = $state;
```

but this still doesn't work. 
I don't get why $state is undefined when i debug it.

I saw it is working fine in many examples other the web.

Comment: where do you call your function, where do you attach a value to `$state`? Can you show more code?

Comment: i am not calling this function. this is a listener it gets called when the url changes.
i have defined my $states in the .config.
i am able to get hold of $state in services and controllers just fine

Comment: if the system says it is not defined, then ... it is not defined. There must be something wrong with another part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason, why `$state` should not be available in `.run()`. I guess there would be some other issue. Here is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/GpHuP0wmMmINYsYsCMgm?p=preview), showing the above in action.

```
// some simple token holder; until set to tru, only main is accessible
.factory('sessionStorage', function(){return {token: false}})

// we do ask for sessionStorage as well
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'sessionStorage', function ($rootScope, $state, sessionStorage) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (evt, toState) {
      if(toState.name === "main"){
        return;
      }
      if (!sessionStorage.token){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go('main');   
      }
    });
}]);
```

The only significant change is that we do ask angular to inject **`sessionStorage`** as well. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GpHuP0wmMmINYsYsCMgm?p=preview)